# beautiful soup find text of path that contains div and span

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python3, I am working on selenium project for a website

the text that i want is under the path `("//div[@class='classname']//span[@class='classname2']).text`

but i cannot extract it without a beautifulsoup

```
for i in postsContainer.extract():
    soup = bs(i)
    people.append([soup.find("div",{"class":"classname"}).text])
```

but It doesn't work without the //span part. How can I insert my path in a beautifulsoup?

If someone can help

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks  --- some html code or an url would be nice

Comment: @HedgeHog here's my path:

    <div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0">
        <span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Hello</span>

I want to extract the word "Hello" using the beautifulsoup that should pass by both; div and span
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

If there would be some more html to inspect, we would maybe find a better solution, but you can use the css selectors in this case

```
soup.select_one('div.css-901oao.r-18jsvk2.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0 > span.css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0').get_text()
```

or:

```
soup.select_one('div.css-901oao.r-18jsvk2.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0 > span').get_text()
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="classname">
    <span class="classname2">text</span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

soup.select_one('div.classname span.classname2').get_text()
```